# jQuery tabs link to another tab

Tags: jquery, select, tabs

How can you link to another tab within a tab?

```
<a href="#tab2">Link to tab</a>
```

Doesn't work, even when the id of the tab content is `tab2`. I need it to be dynamic, so I can't simply use `jQuery` tabs select function, as I do not know the index number of the tab.

Comment: spare some source code please :)

Comment: How are the tabs populated?

Comment: There's no need, it's the default <ul><li><a href="#tab1"></li></ul><div id="tab1"></div>

Comment: But you just mentioned that they are dynamic.

Comment: No, I said the link needs to be dynamic...so I can just use the id of the tab, rather than an onClick to the specific index number of the tab.

Comment: What's the relationship between the tab and the anchor element? there has to be something..is it the fragment identifier?

Comment: Still the question is not clear. Please give some more explanation.

Comment: The id, basically my tabs are fine, but I want to link from let's say tab2 to tab3, within tab2's content area. Usually an anchor (as above) would work, but it doesn't work with jQuery tabs. You need to use .tabs select function, but that requires the index number for the tab you want to go to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery UI select function is the only way out. Anyhow, you need to find the dynamic id of the other tab. As you said, your tabs id gonna be dynamic, but since all the content of the ui tab comes under same page, id should be accessible. You should provide ID to jquery ui tab links in pattern like `#tabs-1`,`#tabs-2`,`#tabs-3` so, you can access the next tab or previous tab easily.

```
$("#tabs").tabs("select", "#tabs-" + dynamicID);
```